# Python/Pandas Iterating through columns

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a DataFrame which looks like this (with many additional columns)

```
          age1     age2      age3     age 4   \
Id#     
1001         5        6         2          8  
1002         7        6         1          0
1003        10        9         7          5
1004         9       12         5          9
```

I am trying write a loop that sums each column with the previous ones before it and returns it to a new DataFrame.
I have started out, simply, with this:

```
New = pd.DataFrame()
New[0] = SFH2.ix[:,0]
for x in SFH2:
    ls = [x,x+1]
    B = SFH2[ls].sum(axis=1)
    New[x] = B

print(New)
```

and the error I get is

```
    ls = [x,x+1]

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I know that int and str are different objects, but how can I overcome this, or is there a different way to iterate through columns?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want the output to be?

Comment: In other words, do you want each column to be the sum of all the columns to the left, or simply that column and a single column to the left (right?).

Comment: I want each column to be the sum of all the columns to the left.

Comment: @cmf05 - I think the best is add desired output to question, maybe in another question you can do it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `cumsum` is what you are looking for:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001     5     6     2     8
1002     7     6     1     0
1003    10     9     7     5
1004     9    12     5     9

In [6]: df.cumsum(axis=1)
Out[6]: 
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001     5    11    13    21
1002     7    13    14    14
1003    10    19    26    31
1004     9    21    26    35
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Clearly I need to get a bit more familiar with pandas.

Comment: @piRSquared Well, OP was a bit ambiguous. The code seemed to imply the rolling sum with window of 2, but the description of the desired output implied `cumsum`

Comment: @cmf05 If you find yourself writing for-loops to work with `pandas` objects, then there is almost always a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.shift(-1,axis=1))
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001   6.0   2.0   8.0   NaN
1002   6.0   1.0   0.0   NaN
1003   9.0   7.0   5.0   NaN
1004  12.0   5.0   9.0   NaN

print (df.add(df.shift(-1,axis=1), fill_value=0))
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001  11.0   8.0  10.0   8.0
1002  13.0   7.0   1.0   0.0
1003  19.0  16.0  12.0   5.0
1004  21.0  17.0  14.0   9.0
```

If need shift with `1` (default parameter, omited):

```
print (df.shift(axis=1))
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001   NaN   5.0   6.0   2.0
1002   NaN   7.0   6.0   1.0
1003   NaN  10.0   9.0   7.0
1004   NaN   9.0  12.0   5.0

print (df.add(df.shift(axis=1), fill_value=0))
      age1  age2  age3  age4
Id#                         
1001   5.0  11.0   8.0  10.0
1002   7.0  13.0   7.0   1.0
1003  10.0  19.0  16.0  12.0
1004   9.0  21.0  17.0  14.0
```